# Vite - Resolve alias for module federation

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, vite

Currently

```
import federation from '@originjs/vite-plugin-federation';
import react from '@vitejs/plugin-react-swc';
import dns from 'dns';
import path from 'path';
import { visualizer } from 'rollup-plugin-visualizer';
import { defineConfig, splitVendorChunkPlugin } from 'vite';
import env from 'vite-plugin-env-compatible';
import svgr from 'vite-plugin-svgr';
import pkg from './package.json';

dns.setDefaultResultOrder('verbatim');

export default defineConfig(({ mode }) => {
  return {
    plugins: [
      react(),
      svgr(),
      env({ prefix: 'REACT_APP' }),
      splitVendorChunkPlugin(),
      federation({
        name: 'ad-host',
        filename: 'remoteEntry.js',
        exposes: {
          './components/BasePaper': './src/components/BasePaper',
        },
        remotes: {
          main: 'http://localhost:3001/assets/remoteEntry.js',
          remote_app: 'http://localhost:4001/assets/remoteEntry.js',
        },
        shared: {
          ...Object.entries(pkg.dependencies).reduce((acc, [key, version]) => {
            acc[key] = {
              requiredVersion: version,
            };
            return acc;
          }, {}),
        },
      }),
    ],
    server: {
      port: 3001,
      host: true,
    },
    preview: {
      port: 3001,
    },
    build: {
      outDir: 'build',
      rollupOptions: {
        plugins: [
          visualizer({
            open: mode === 'dev',
            gzipSize: true,
            brotliSize: true,
          }),
        ],
      },
    },
    esbuild: {
      loader: 'jsx',
    },
    optimizeDeps: {
      esbuildOptions: {
        define: {
          global: 'globalThis',
        },
        loader: {
          '.js': 'jsx',
        },
      },
    },
    resolve: {
      alias: {
        entries: [{ find: 'remote_app', replacement: 'remote_app' }],
        '~': path.resolve(__dirname, 'src'),
        components: path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/components'),
        utils: path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/utils'),
        containers: path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/containers'),
        images: path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/images'),
        media: path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/media'),
        hooks: path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/hooks'),
        styled: path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/styled'),
        appContext: path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/appContext'),
        'redux/store': path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/redux/store'),
        'redux/models/app': path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/redux/models/app'),
      },
    },
  };
});
```

on my code i put `const ModuleA = React.lazy(() => import('remote_app/ModuleA'));`

But keep getting `Failed to resolve import "remote_app/ModuleA"`.

without setting up alias the error is same. what to put on resolve to fix this? I've tested the code without `resolve` block it works just fine.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried removing this line?
`entries: [{ find: 'remote_app', replacement: 'remote_app' }],`